# Error with conversion from shapefile to GeoJSON

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, geopandas

Currently, I am trying to transform a shapefile to GeoJSON, I have the `.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf` and `.prj` files.

In order to do this I have the following code:

```
import json
import geopandas as gpd
import shapefile

SHP_FILE = '00ent.shp'
DBF_FILE = '00ent.dbf'
JSON_FILE = "mexico.geojson"

geodf = gpd.read_file(DBF_FILE)
geodf.plot()
```

[image]

The problem is that these points in the geometry, are not a lat, long points, and I want to convert to lat, lang in order to convert the file in a geoJson with the lat long coordinates.

Data:

```
CVEGEO  CVE_ENT NOMGEO  geometry
0   01  01  Aguascalientes  POLYGON ((2470517.824 1155028.588, 2470552.248...
1   02  02  Baja California MULTIPOLYGON (((1493197.166 1849625.247, 14934...
2   03  03  Baja California Sur MULTIPOLYGON (((1694656.344 1227647.637, 16946...
3   04  04  Campeche    MULTIPOLYGON (((3544897.199 946994.621, 354491...
4   05  05  Coahuila de Zaragoza    POLYGON ((2469954.193 1978522.993, 2469982.807...
5   06  06  Colima  MULTIPOLYGON (((1157633.318 768573.525,
```

How can I translate this to lat long?

I can use another Python library if is necessary.

Comment: You can use QGIS (http://qgis.org) to  change the coordinate system of your data and then export your data to GeoJson . If you need to get a point that represents your polygon you can calculate the centroid. The conversion can also be done in QGIS

Comment: The problem is that I need can do this without online tool or other software only with a python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with only geopandas:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

shp_file = "00ent.shp"
json_file = "mexico.geojson"

# Read in data
gdf = gpd.read_file(shp_file)
# Reproject to Lat/Long: http://epsg.io/4326
gdf_4326 = gdf.to_crs(epsg='4326')
# Write to file
gdf_4326.to_file(json_file, driver="GeoJSON")
```

Comment: is http://epsg.io/4326 a standard?, what projection was using the current file? Thanks

Comment: EPSG:4326 is World Geodetic System 1984, used in GPS.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES, you can see the the projection used in the original file with `gdf.crs`. That should print the EPSG string that you can use with http://epsg.io/ to get more info.